# NSString to NSData Failing in Encoding

Tags: xml, iphone, nsxmlparser, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to use NSXmlParser to parse ISO-8859-1 data. Using Apple's own example for parsing ISO-8859-1, I have the following.

```
// path to xml file
NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sampleFileName ofType:@"xml"];

// string of xml contents
NSString *xmlFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"contents: %@", xmlFileContents);
```

I see that in the console, the contents of the string is accurate.

However when I try to convert it to an NSData object (for use with the parser), I do the following.

```
NSData *xmlData = [xmlFileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But then when my didStartElement delegate gets called, I see `Â` showing up which I think is from an encoding discrepancy.

Can NSXmlParser handle ISO-8859-1 and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't NSXMLParser understand the encoding it's dealing with from the `<?xml?>` declaration?

Comment: I would think so. My XML starts with:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

And like I said the NSString contents log correctly. Converting it to NSData, kicking off the NSXmlParser and dumping things found in didStartElement yields these Â characters in certain areas.

Comment: Rather than reading the file into an NSString and then converting that to NSData, it might simplify things to just do [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath]

Comment: Yeah I was actually using [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath] originally and noticed the spurious characters from the ISO encoding. Then I did the NSString method just to make sure it was reading it into a string correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else ends up on this thread trying to figure out how the heck to get XML that starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` read properly by NSXmlParser, here is what I got working.

```
// path to xml file
NSString *xmlFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sampleFileName ofType:@"xml"];

// string of xml contents (read in NSUTF8StringEncoding)
NSString *xmlFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:xmlFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// interpret string of XML contents as ISO-8859-1 (NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
NSData *xmlData = [xmlFileContents dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

// spawn new thread to parse data
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parseLineData:) toTarget:self withObject:xmlData];
```

Reading in the XML contents as `NSUTF8StringEncoding` and then into `NSData` as `NSUTF8StringEncoding` was the only way I avoided the spurious `Â` characters.