# iOS parsing of spanish letters in XML appearing strangely

Tags: ios, xml, encoding, utf-8

I'm building an iOS app that, as part of its functionality parses an XML document and sets some labels based on the data there. I've run into trouble a few times parsing a few characters - specifically, the spanish character `ó` is appearing as `√≥`. According to documentation, the XML I'm parsing is supposed to be UTF-8 encoded, and when I parse it to an XML file within the app I use NSUTF8StringEncoding, so I'm not sure what else could be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing with the XML that means you end up specifying a string encoding? I ask because `NSXMLParser` takes an `NSData` directly without you specifying an encoding, and `NSURL` or an `NSInputStream` rather than an `NSString`.

Comment: This may or may not apply to you, but here is another post about similar Unicode issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485920/nsstring-to-nsdata-failing-in-encoding

Comment: I turn the NSData into an NSString via initWithBytes:length:encoding for use with TBXML